# ios7 - UITableViewCell with UIPickerView and UIDatePicker built inline

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uipickerview

A [number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228921/converting-apple-datecell-example-to-use-uipickerview-instead-of-uidatepickervie) of posts are dealing with the subject: How to make an [inline UIPickerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973573/ios7-how-to-display-a-date-picker-in-place-in-a-table-view). As I am lazy, can anyone point me to a code snippet. To be honest, I find the Apple DateCell sample pedantic - there has to be an a more elegant method.

Is the dateCell app a good place to start? or are there other better links. I would appreciate any advice.

If you read this and do not understand my requirements / goal, please see the two posts referenced above or simply download the [Apple Sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/DateCell/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008866) (dev. account required).

Comment: Hi there David, I'm currently struggling with the same sort of problem. By any chance (now that you solved the problem), do you have any example code I would be able to take a look at? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Narner, let me refresh my memory and get back to you.

Comment: That'd be amazing David, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: I ended up using an expand / contract tableviewcell structure, integrating this control by Tom Fewster: https://github.com/wannabegeek  This control includes an inline date picker.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks David, I tried running the project from that link, but unfortunately it was missing a file. I gave this ago, but ran into a problem (at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28353639/attempting-to-add-an-inline-uidatepicker-to-a-uitableviewcell). Would you mind taking a look at all?

Comment: You have a new answer there, that looks reasonable. There is also this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973573/ios-7-how-to-display-a-date-picker-in-place-in-a-table-view?lq=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use another - maybe simpler - solution to solve this.

Image that we have two cells

1. Date label cell
2. Date picker cell

Most of the "magic" is within the table view delegate's `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView:)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat heightForRow = tableView.rowHeight;

    if ([self isDatePickerRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]) {
        heightForRow = (self.isDatePickerShown) ? heightOfDatePicker : 0.0;
    }

    return heightForRow;
}
```

So you simply "hide" the date picker by returning a height of `0.0`.

---

In the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method you do the toggling:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([self isDateLabelRowAtIndexPath:indexPath])
    {
        self.datePickerIsShown = ! self.isDatePickerShown;
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView endUpdates];
    }
}
```

Calling the empty `beginUpdates` `endUpdates` block forces the table to call the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` again (animated) and nicely fades in or out the date picker cell.

---

When the date picker cell is the last one in a section you might also want to update the **date label** cell's `separatorInset` to `UIEdgeInsetsZero` when the date picker is hidden and to the default value when it's shown.

---

**EDIT:**

For completeness: `datePickerIsShown` is a simple boolean:

```
@property(nonatomic, getter = isDatePickerShown) BOOL datePickerIsShown;
```

The methods `isDateLabelRowAtIndexPath:` and `isDatePickerRowAtIndexPath:` are just helper methods that compare a given `indexPath` to the known index path of the appropriate cell:

```
- (BOOL)isDatePickerRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return ([self.datePickerIndexPath compare:indexPath] == NSOrderedSame);
}
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

There's one additional step missing: Make sure that you set the date picker cell's `clipsToBounds` property to `YES`, otherwise you'll get some view glitches.

Comment: Thanks Florian. I will play with this for the Date Cell. Have you implemented something similar for a UIPickerView cell?

Comment: Florian, could you please show the two methods: isDatePickerRowAtIndexPath:indexPath and isDatePickerShown (many thanks )

Comment: As of iOS 11 this is still a great solution, thanks!